# What is C# code doing:

Tags: c#, constructor-chaining

In the following code:

```
public class A
{
public A():this(null){}
public A(string b){/*code here*/}
}
```

What is the use of first constructor?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first constructor is passing `null` into parameter b of the second constructor.

Thus if you call `new A()` it will be the same as calling `new A(null)`

Comment: To be precise, defining multiple constuctors is constructor overloading, and having those constructors call each other is constructor chaining. The code that calls another constructor, for example `this()` or `base(foo)`, is called a constructor initializer.

Answer (score 5):

When you have a constructor with a parameter

```
public A(string b){ /* code here */ }

public A():this("") { }  //default
```

the default constructor actually calls the "parameter constructor" with "" as a parameter. You are passing a parameter. This is done in order to avoid writing the same code twice

Answer (score 3):

It's a [constructor overload](http://dotnetperls.com/constructor-overload-this).

I agree it doesn't seem to be very useful in this case because most likely the uninitialised value for a string is null anyway.

See also [Constructors in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html)

Comment: There might be some other code which reqires that A has a default constructor. But I Think you the :this(null) is not required.

Answer (score 3):

this happens when you're overloading constructors.

in your example the empty contructor `public A():this(null){}` looks for a constructor that can take in an object value of null. since a string is an object that can take nulls, it calls that constructor.

this example seems very simplistic.

a more meaningful example (but still keeping it basic):

```
 public class AddNumbers
{
   public AddNumbers():this(100, 100)
   {     }

   public AddNumbers(int x, int y)
   {     
         int sum = x + y;
         Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());
   }    
}
```

in this example, when a calling program calls the empty constructor, it will output 200. because it is calling the AddNumbers method with x = 100, y = 100.

i know it's a simple example but i hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a default constructor that calls second with b==null.

Comment: Operations that happen behind the scenes (such as data-binding and serialization) will call the default constructor so it's sometimes useful to explicitly define what you want to happen in the default (i.e. parameterless) constructor

Answer (score 0):

Some interfaces or designers require there to be a "parameterless" constructor.

This method comes in handy in those times.

Answer (score 0):

Having a parameterless default constructor is required when object initialization is used:

```
Employee e = new Employee() {FirstName="John", LastName="Smith"};
```

In this case, I probably would not use constructor chaining, though. Constructor overloading gives you an alternative way to initialize with parameters. Where constructor chaining is really useful is in making constructor parameters optional; C# doesn't support optional parameters (yet).

"Best practice" will depend on the situation, usage, architecture, requirements, etc. (ISO Consulting Rule Number One: "It depends.")